# Сложный запрос Join

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM log lg 
            LEFT JOIN categorysubscribetotype cst
                ON cst.CategoryTypeCategorysubscribetotype = lg.LogType
            LEFT JOIN cst.Tablesubscribetotype ON cst.TableIdsubscribetotype = lg.LogIdNote
```

Выдает ошибку: #1146 - Table 'cst.Tablesubscribetotype' doesn't exist

Как-то так нужно сделать - правда не работает:

```
   SELECT * 
FROM log AS lg

LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT categorysubscribetotype.Tablesubscribetotype AS fl1, categorysubscribetotype.TableIdsubscribetotype AS fl2
        FROM categorysubscribetotype
        WHERE CategoryTypeCategorysubscribetotype = lg.LogType
) AS QR1

        ON QR1.fl2 = log.LogIdNote
```

Comment: Потому что нет таблицы с именем `cst.Tablesubscribetotype`.

`cst` объявлен как алиас для таблицы `categorysubscribetotype`. Что вы имели в виду выражением `cst.Tablesubscribetotype` ?

Comment: Вопрос в том что LEFT JOIN categorysubscribetotype cst возвращает поле Tablesubscribetotype по которому хочу сделать еще один LEFT JOIN

Comment: Сообщается, что таблицы не существует.
По всей видимости, в cst нет таблицы с названием «Tablesubscribetotype»  - может ошибка в названии таблицы?

Comment: >  LEFT JOIN categorysubscribetotype cst возвращает поле

LEFT JOIN не возвращает полей. Он перемножает вам две таблицы, фильтрует по условию, сохраняя null-ы в левой таблице.

Может быть вы не до конца понимаете, что происходит при JOIN? Если не трудно - опишите структуру таблиц (столбцы и пару строк с данными).

Comment: В таблице categorysubscribetotype есть 100% поля: Tablesubscribetotype TableIdsubscribetotype

Comment: Т.е. таблиц всего две `categorysubscribetotype` и  `log`?

Comment: Да - верно

Comment: как поля `Tablesubscribetotype` и `TableIdsubscribetotype` связаны с таблицей `log`?

Comment: Эти поля указывают на связь с другой таблицей. Tablesubscribetotype -> указывает на таблицу articles, TableIdsubscribetotype -> указывает по какому полю связывать с этой таблицей

Comment: Пока вы не добавите в вопрос схему данных (таблицы и связи в любом виде), читающим будет сложно понять, что вы хотите.

Если вы хотите из поля `Tablesubscribetotype` взять строку с названием какой-то таблицы и тут же сделать JOIN, то так не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой вариант.

Первым шагом вы получаете возможные типы таблиц:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(cst.Tablesubscribetotype), cst.TableIdsubscribetotype 
FROM 
  log as lg LEFT JOIN
  categorysubscribetotype cst ON cst.CategoryTypeCategorysubscribetotype = lg.LogType
```

Допустим вам вернулись пары `Table1`-`Table1Id`, `Table2`-`Table2Id`, `Table3`-`Table3Id`...
Вторым шагом пробегаетесь по этим парам и склеиваете запрос:

```
(SELECT * 
 FROM 
   log AS lg LEFT JOIN
   Table1 t1 on t1.Table1Id = log.LogIdNote )
UNION
(SELECT * 
 FROM 
   log AS lg LEFT JOIN
   Table2 t2 on t2.Table2Id = log.LogIdNote)
UNION
(SELECT * 
 FROM 
   log AS lg LEFT JOIN
   Table3 t3 on t3.Table1Id = log.LogIdNote)
UNION
....
```

Вместо * нужно указывать конкретные столбцы, так чтобы типы данных для n-ных столбцов в каждом SELECT-е совпадали.

Comment: Будем думать...спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

А так?

```
SELECT * FROM log lg 
            LEFT JOIN categorysubscribetotype cst
                ON cst.CategoryTypeCategorysubscribetotype = lg.LogType
            OR cst.TableIdsubscribetotype = lg.LogIdNote
```

Comment: Совсем не то...

Comment: Посмотрите мое дополнение к вопросу - оно должно навести на правильные мысли

Comment: Ну и ладно.
Лучше приведите пример данных, и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: > с таблицей(промежуточная) categorysubscribetotype, в которой хранится имя таблицы (Tablesubscribetotype) и название поля(TableIdsubscribetotype) этой таблицы для связи

Так не получится. JOIN может происходить только с конкретной таблицей. Представьте себе этот процесс так: СУБД берет 2 таблицы, составляет все возможные сочетания строк, а потом вычеркивает строки не подходящие под условие. Поэтому нельзя динамически выбрать таблицу для JOIN-а.

Comment: Я Вас понял. Посмотрите пожалуйста мое дополнение в вопросе - примерно это хочу сделать. Спасибо